# How to split text by comma into lines?

Tags: python, string, split, newline

How to split a line of text by comma onto separate lines?

#### Code

```
text = "ACCOUNTNUMBER=Accountnumber,ACCOUNTSOURCE=Accountsource,ADDRESS_1__C=Address_1__C,ADDRESS_2__C"
fields = text.split(",")
text = "\n".join(fields)
```

#### Issue & Expected

But "\n" did not work. The result expected is that it adds new lines like:

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER=Accountnumber,
ACCOUNTSOURCE=Accountsource,
ADDRESS_1__C=Address_1__C,
ADDRESS_2__C
```

Note:  I **run it on Google Colab**

Comment: How do you check if it worked?  What platform do you run it on?  What's the actual result?

Comment: The shown code doesn't produce any output.

Comment: It works fine. Maybe you tried to print ```fields``` when the actual result is stored in ```text```. Try printing ```text```

Comment: You should check with `print(text)`, not with `text`

Comment: Try `print('\n'.join(text.split(',')))`

Answer (score 1):

if you want the commas to stay there you can use this code:

```
text = "ACCOUNTNUMBER=Accountnumber,ACCOUNTSOURCE=Accountsource,ADDRESS_1__C=Address_1__C,ADDRESS_2__C"
fields = text.split(",")
print(",\n".join(fields))
```

Comment: With an eye for detail, this great answer shows a detail from given "Expected output" - **the comma was kept at line-end**.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should give this output

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER=Accountnumber
ACCOUNTSOURCE=Accountsource
ADDRESS_1__C=Address_1__C
ADDRESS_2__C
```

But if you want to seperate it by commas(,). You should add comma(,) with `\n` use `text = ",\n".join(fields)` instead of `text = "\n".join(fields)`
So the final code should be

```
text="ACCOUNTNUMBER=Accountnumber,ACCOUNTSOURCE=Accountsource,ADDRESS_1__C=Address_1__C,ADDRESS_2__C"

fields = text.split(",")
text = ",\n".join(fields)
print (text)
```

It will give your desirable output.

Answer (score 0):

A more cross-compatible way could be to use `os.linesep`. It's my understanding that it's safer to do this for code that might be running on both Linux, Windows and other OSes:

```
import os
print("hello" + os.linesep + "fren")
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to use print then it worked!, thank all you guys

Comment: This is because in the interactive Python console the assignment `text = ..` just shows the escaped `\n` like `Address_1__C,\nADDRESS_2__C`, whereas the `print()` statement represents or interprets the newline by adding the line-wrap in console.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Looks like this is a "thank you" answer, typically we want answers to be unique bits of helpful information. So in your case, the best course of action would be to select the most useful answer, mark it as accepted and delete this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() :

```py
text = "ACCOUNTNUMBER=Accountnumber,ACCOUNTSOURCE=Accountsource,ADDRESS_1__C=Address_1__C,ADDRESS_2__C"

print(text.replace(',',",\n"))
```

result:

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER=Accountnumber,
ACCOUNTSOURCE=Accountsource,
ADDRESS_1__C=Address_1__C,
ADDRESS_2__C
```